# Problem using ExtendedPersistenceContext and ApplicationException

Tags: exception, transactions, ejb, seam

I'm trying to use a ExtendedPersistenceContext to implement the detached object pattern using EJB 3 and Seam.

I also have a business rule engine that processes my object when I merge it **based on the data on the database**.

When something goes wrong in the business rule, the app launches an Exception marked with

> @ApplicationException(rollback = true)

Unfortunately, according to the EJB specific and this question from SO [Forcing a transaction to rollback on validation errors in Seam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822746/forcing-a-transaction-to-rollback-on-validation-errors-in-seam), that annotations forces all the object to become detached.

So basically my object is in the same state as before (it contains modification made by the user) but it can't resolve its relations using the ExtendedPersistenceContext, since it's in the Detached state.

This breaks all my page, since I have AJAX calls that I want to resolve even after the failure of the Business Engine.

I can't merge the object again otherwise the modification will be propagated on the DB, and I don't want to do it if there is an ApplicationException.

I want to rollback the transaction if a business validation fail, but I want my object to be still in a persistent state so that it can resolve its relations using the extended persistence context.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you wan't to commit changes or rollback in the exception? Can you please explain what you want to accomplish?

Comment: I want to rollback the transaction, but still be able to use the object as before.

Comment: Rollback will automatically happen since you are using @ApplicationException(rollback=true). Is this not the case? Are you seeing commit in rollback?

Comment: There is indeed a rollback, but my object is in an "inconsistent" state, and I can't use it as before.

Comment: Then try to use `entityManager.refresh()` to restore the object

Comment: If I use refresh() the object get reloaded from the database, and all my changes are lost.

Comment: But you say you want to rollback, this means all your changes will get lost. Either you want to rollback and discard all changes, or you want to save the changes. Or is there a third option?

Comment: There is a third option: rollback the transition, so that the changes don't go on the DB, but keep the object in memory with my changes.

Answer (score 0):

To detach a single object can use `entityManager.detach(object)`, else can use `entityManager.clear()` to detach all underlying objects for a EntityManager.

You can clone the objects to maintain the changes being made & prevent them from rolling back on exception. The changes are to be done on cloned object & then apply them to the managed object before persistence.

If the object is detached, then have to perform `entityManager.refresh(object)` to make it managed & then applying changes of cloned object accordingly to it.